# Linear Regression Gradient

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, regression, linear-regression

I have very basic sample of Linear Regression. Implementation below (without Regularization)

```
class Learning:

    def assume(self, weights, x):
        return np.dot(x, np.transpose(weights))

    def cost(self, weights, x, y, lam):
        predict = self.assume(weights, x) \
            .reshape(len(x), 1)

        val = np.sum(np.square(predict - y), axis=0)
        assert val is not None

        assert val.shape == (1,)
        return val[0] / 2 * len(x)

    def grad(self, weights, x, y, lam):
        predict = self.assume(weights, x)\
            .reshape(len(x), 1)

        val = np.sum(np.multiply(
            x, (predict - y)), axis=0)
        assert val is not None

        assert val.shape == weights.shape
        return val / len(x)
```

And I want to check gradient, that it works, with `scipy.optimize`.

```
learn = Learning()
INPUTS = np.array([[1, 2],
          [1, 3],
          [1, 6]])
OUTPUTS = np.array([[3], [5], [11]])
WEIGHTS = np.array([1, 1])

t_check_grad = scipy.optimize.check_grad(
    learn.cost, learn.grad, WEIGHTS,INPUTS, OUTPUTS, 0)
print(t_check_grad)
# Output will be 73.2241602235811!!!
```

I manually checked all computation from start to end. And it's actually right implementatino. But in output I see extremely big difference! What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cost function you should return

```
val[0] / (2 * len(x))
```

instead of `val[0] / 2 * len(x)`. Then you will have

```
print(t_check_grad)
# 1.20853633278e-07
```

Comment: It happens sometimes ... :)

Comment: BTW, size of x(and weights) metters? Because I have using the same sourcefor few examples with more than 20k features, and gradient stay around the ~30.

Comment: @GensaGames you mean `t_check_grad` stays close to 30? I think it should not be that large, can you try printing the cost function, the gradient values and one computed using the finite difference? also, you may want to use the `bias` term.